# why the ts-transform-paths did not replace the @ alias import path

Tags: typescript

I want to use [ts-transform-paths](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript-transform-paths) to transform the typescript alias path, first install the plugin:

```
yarn add ts-transform-paths -D
```

then add config in the `tsconfig.json`:

```
// Note: To transform paths for both the output .js and .d.ts files, you need both of the below entries
    "plugins": [
      // Transform paths in output .js files
      { "transform": "typescript-transform-paths" },

      // Transform paths in output .d.ts files (Include this line if you output declarations files)
      { "transform": "typescript-transform-paths", "afterDeclarations": true }
    ]
```

this is the full `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": { 
    /* Language and Environment */
    "target": "es5",                                  /* Set the JavaScript language version for emitted JavaScript and include compatible library declarations. */
    
    /* Modules */
    "module": "esnext",                                /* Specify what module code is generated. */
    
    /* Emit */
    "declaration": true,                              /* Generate .d.ts files from TypeScript and JavaScript files in your project. */
    "outDir": "./dist", 
    "esModuleInterop": true,                             /* Emit additional JavaScript to ease support for importing CommonJS modules. This enables `allowSyntheticDefaultImports` for type compatibility. */
    // "preserveSymlinks": true,                         /* Disable resolving symlinks to their realpath. This correlates to the same flag in node. */
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,            /* Ensure that casing is correct in imports. */

    /* Type Checking */
    "strict": true,                                      /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "paths": {
      "@net/*":["net/*"],
      "@auth/*":["auth/*"],
    },
    // Note: To transform paths for both the output .js and .d.ts files, you need both of the below entries
    "plugins": [
      // Transform paths in output .js files
      { "transform": "typescript-transform-paths" },

      // Transform paths in output .d.ts files (Include this line if you output declarations files)
      { "transform": "typescript-transform-paths", "afterDeclarations": true }
    ]                                 /* Skip type checking all .d.ts files. */
  },
  "exclude": [
    "dist"
  ]
}
```

but when I build the project with command tsc, the dist folder file import path did not replaced by the plugin. still looks like this:

```
import { ResponseCode } from "@net/rest/ResponseCode";
import { AuthHandler } from "@auth/extension/AuthHandler";
```

why the path alias replace did not work? what should I do to make it work?

Answer (score 2):

did you previously install `ts-patch` on your project as indicated here https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript-transform-paths ?
It works like a charm for me, you should add it like so `<yarn|npm|pnpm> add -D ts-patch` and add this in your `package.json` as indicated https://github.com/nonara/ts-patch :

```
"scripts": {
    "prepare": "ts-patch install -s",
}
```

Comment: @BarryMichaelDoyle This answer is utilfull for me, this module resolve my issue.

Comment: It is important to run "ts-patch install" first